# Center image with JavaScript for Firebase

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to display the center of an image, in a `<img>` tag that has a `border-radius` of `50%`, for an image that is a circle. The problem is that the `image` is shown from a firebase storage file instead of a url.

I have tried with JavaScript code to show the center of the image and it works just great, if I do this:

```css
.box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden
}

.wh {
  height: 100%!important
}

.ww {
  width: 100%!important
}
```

```html
<div class="box" style="border-radius:50%;">
  <img src="1.jpg" />
</div>
<input type="file" id="fileButton" /> <input type="submit" value="Upload" id="uploadButton" />
```

I get this result, which is what I want:

[image]

But if I use the image from firebase (which is completely the same image btw) then I get this result:

[image]

Here is the code with Firebase used and also the JavaScript for centering the image (which is also used making the url image above):

```js
var fileButton = document.getElementById('fileButton');
var uploadButton = document.getElementById('uploadButton');

fileButton.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  var file = e.target.files[0];

  //Create a storage ref in firebase
  var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('test/profilePic.jpg');

  console.log(file.height);

  uploadButton.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    storageRef.put(file).then(function() {
      window.open('profil.php?error=1', '_top');
    });


  });
});

var storage = firebase.storage();
var storageRef = storage.ref();
var spaceRef = storageRef.child('test/profilePic.jpg');

storageRef.child('test/profilePic.jpg').getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {

  var test = url;
  document.getElementById('profilePicture').src = test;

}).catch(function(error) {

});



$('.box').each(function() {


  //set size
  var th = $(this).height(), //box height
    tw = $(this).width(), //box width
    im = $(this).children('img'), //image
    ih = im.height(), //inital image height
    iw = im.width(); //initial image width
  if (ih > iw) { //if portrait
    im.addClass('ww').removeClass('wh'); //set width 100%
  } else { //if landscape
    im.addClass('wh').removeClass('ww'); //set height 100%
  }
  //set offset
  var nh = im.height(), //new image height
    nw = im.width(), //new image width
    hd = (nh - th) / 2,
    wd = (nw - tw) / 2;
  if (nh < nw) { //if portrait
    im.css({
      marginLeft: '-' + wd + 'px',
      marginTop: 0
    }); //offset left
  } else {
    im.css({
      marginTop: '-' + hd + 'px',
      marginLeft: '0px'
    }); //offset top
  }
});
```

```css
.box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden
}

.wh {
  height: 100%!important
}

.ww {
  width: 100%!important
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box" style="border-radius:50%;">
  <img id="profilePicture" />
</div>
<input type="file" id="fileButton" /> <input type="submit" value="Upload" id="uploadButton" />
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: what is `uploadButton` and what is `fileButton` in your code?

Comment: The snippet is not running. Add jQuery and see if you are not missing anything else.

Comment: @Dekel I have added the buttons. It is just a file button and a button that saves the image to firebase. Those functions are working, the problem is the script that should show the center of the image, as the center of the border radius, as it does when I am using the src inside the img tag, instead of receiving the src with firebase.

Comment: @Juan jQuery is added to this project? I don't know what you mean. The script is working when using the src inside the img tag instead of receiving the image url from firebase storage.

Comment: When I click "run the snippet" I get two errors. One of them references '$' which I guess is jQuery not being added to the snippet. When you edit the snippet look at the left of the screen. There you can choose the version of jquery you are using.

Comment: You need to apply the `css` to the image after you set the `document.getElementById('profilePicture').src = test;`

Answer (score 0):

You could have a few issues here.

1. You could be having an async issue ( You are setting styles in JavaScript before the Firebase returns with the data ).
2. You should have your styling in CSS.
3. Never use !important, understand and use [CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

If you set up your CSS correctly it will handle this for you. I took out firebase and a lot of other unnecessary parts to keep it clean. the issue is either an async issue or not utilizing CSS correctly. I simulate an async change with `setTimeout` in JavaScript.

```js
setTimeout(function(){
  document.getElementById("imageid").src="http://www.threeriversschools.org/pages/district-blog/image/section-image/soccer-194.jpg";
},3000);
```

```css
.box{
height:100px;
width:100px;
overflow:hidden
}
.box img{
  width : 100%;
  height : 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" style="border-radius:50%;" >
<img id="imageid" src="http://cdn-mf1.heartyhosting.com/sites/mensfitness.com/files/styles/wide_videos/public/soccer-kick-goal-kickoff-1280.jpg?itok=z-E-ZQem" />
</div>
```